# A formal name for "smallest" and "largest" partition

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, set-partition

Consider a set $A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$,
is there any terminology for the following partitions of $A$ ?

(1) $A=\{ \{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\},\{5\} \}$

(2) $A=\{\{1,2,3,4,5\}\}$.

Comment: I am not sure to which extent these names are used, but Google Books returns some results for
[trivial partition](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22trivial+partition%22) for the second one and
[discrete partition](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22discrete+partition%22) or
[singleton partition](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22singleton+partition%22) for the first one.

Comment: Okay. Thanks! Maybe this is formal name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do not think that there is terminology, which would be universally agreed.
However, Google search suggests that some people use the following names:
*trivial partition* for the partition $\{A\}$ and *discrete partition* or *singleton partition* for the partition the partition $\{\{a\};a\in A\}$.

Interestingly enough [ProofWiki Article](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Trivial_Partition) suggests that trivial partition is used for both of them and calls the partition $\{A\}$ singleton partition, although no reference is given there. The name used for $\{\{a\}; a\in A\}$ at ProofWiki is *partition of singletons*.

Some examples of the use of the names mentioned above:

- Introduction to Abstract Algebra By W. Keith Nicholson uses the name trivial partition and singleton partition, see [p.19](http://books.google.sk/books?id=KNufK-P-6WoC&pg=PA19)
- An Introduction to Measure Theory By Terence Tao uses the name discrete partition, see [p.68](http://books.google.sk/books?id=4_wqWCfZCA0C&pg=PA68)

Google Books:

- [trivial partition](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22trivial+partition%22)
- [discrete partition](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22discrete+partition%22)
- [singleton partition](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22singleton+partition%22)
- [partition of singletons](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22partition+of+singletons%22)

Answer (score 6):

Suppose that $A$ is a non-empty set and $P_1,P_2$ are two partitions of $A$. We say that $P_1$ *refines* $P_2$ if for every $B\in P_1$ there is $C\in P_2$ such that $B\subseteq C$. This means that $P_1$ was a result of partitioning each part of $P_2$.

We also say that $P_1$ is *finer* than $P_2$; that $P_1$ is a *refinement* of $P_2$; or that $P_2$ is *coarser* than $P_1$.

It is a nice exercise to verify that the relation $x\prec y\iff x\text{ refines }y$ is a partial order over the partitions of $A$, in fact it is a lattice. Every two partitions has a least-refinement and a maximal-coarse partitions.

One can now see that the partition to singletons is the maximum of this partial order. Indeed it is *the finest* partition. Similarly the partition into a single part is *the coarsest* partition, and it is the minimum of the order.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Both Martin's and Asaf's answers are excellent. However, I can only choose either.