# Is there a standard name for the relation $X \times Y$?

Tags: terminology, relations

Given sets $X$ and $Y$, is there a standard name for the relation $f : X \rightarrow Y$ whose graph equals $X \times Y$? Something like the full/maximum/top/total/complete relation?

Comment: I’ve usually called it the *total relation* from $X$ to $Y$.

Comment: "*Trivial relation*" seems to be common when $X=Y$, at least.

Comment: @ZevChonoles, I'm not really keen on 'trivial relation' since its not clear whether we mean the bottom relation or the top relation. But thank you for the information though.

Comment: I think "full relation" is best, because it has a natural counterpart in "empty relation". While "maximal relation" has also a natural counterpart "minimal relation", the latter might be interpreted as relation where there's exactly one pair of related elements (because otherwise all elements are unrelated). "Top" also has a natural counterpart "bottom", but the meaning is not as obvious (what does it mean for a relation to be higher than another one?). "total" and "complete" don't have natural counterparts, as far as I can see.

Comment: There is [an older question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153276/a-formal-name-of-this-partition) about terminology for partitions corresponding to such equivalence relations. (Of course, this is for the case $X=Y$.)

Comment: (LTTP) At least for $X=Y$, I've also seen _'universal relation'_. This is also what Wikipedia uses: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation . And perhaps the _universal relation_ from $X$ to $Y$ would suffice.