# Is the finest partition on $\mathbf{R}$ just $\mathbf{R}$?

Tags: category-theory, order-theory

Does the poset of all partitions of the real numbers (ordered by fineness), $\text{Prt}\,\mathbf{R}$, contain a copy of $\mathbf{R}$?  I'm imagining something analogous to the discrete topology on $\mathbf{R}$. More specifically, I'm thinking about a terminal object in the canonical category induced by the posetal structure on $\text{Prt}\,\mathbf{R}$.

If we have a correspondence between partitions of $\mathbf{R}$ and surjections $f \colon \mathbf{R} \twoheadrightarrow  A$, then the identity function seems a perfectly good candidate for a partition: $\text{id}_\mathbf{R} \colon \mathbf{R} \twoheadrightarrow \mathbf{R}$.

I'd appreciate anyone dropping in the standard terminology or directions to appropriate literature.

Comment: Definitely! Remember partitions are just equivalence relations, and so you're looking at the lattice of equivalence relations on $\mathbb{R}$, ordered by inclusion (viewing them as subsets of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$). The maximal such element is the analogue of the indiscrete topology, where every element is related to every other element. The minimal such relation is the analogue of the discrete topology, where each element is related only to itself.

Comment: By $\mathrm{id}_\mathbf{R}:\mathbf R\twoheadrightarrow\mathbf R$, do you just mean $\mathrm{id}:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$?

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish Yes, but the double-headed arrow specifies surjection in the category of sets. (Of course, $\text{id}$ is a bijection and therefore surjective.) I emphasize surjection because of the correspondence between partitions on a set, and surjections from the set. Also, I prefer a bold upright $\mathbf{R}$ to a blackboard bold $\mathbb{R}$, which is less common but still conventional.

Comment: @Timtro Excellent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*There's nothing special about the reals here, so I'll just talk about an arbitrary set $X$.*

---

Basically, **yes**.

The finest partition on a set $X$ isn't *exactly* $X$ itself; rather, it's $$\{\{x\}: x\in X\}$$ ($\{x\}$ and $x$ are distinct objects). If we choose to represent partitions by functions, then this partition is indeed represented by the identity map on $X$.

As far as terminology goes, I don't think there is a standard one - see the discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/153285/28111) for example - and in particular "trivial partition" is used to refer to both this partition and the partition with a single class. In my opinion the phrase "*discrete* partition" is unambiguous, but I don't think it's universally used (although I have seen it used sometimes).

Comment: Yes, of course you're right: I should have generalised from the real numbers. I think my hesitation was because I worry about “gotchas” in dense infinite sets. I'm not a mathematician, but I have two on my PhD defence committee, and I'm worried about public embarrassment from neglect of some such important subtlety. I suspect I'll be posting a lot of silly questions, born of insecurity, as I finalise my first thesis draft. Thanks for your answer.